# Is it ok to calling save method multiple times in same method for django model object?

Tags: django, django-models

Say, there is a method creates an model object and adds values to model objects fields.

```
def main_method():
    obj, created = ModelA.objects.get_or_create(a="asd", b=1)
```

Some imported data will be append to relevant fields:

```
    obj.c = "qwe"
    obj.d = 2
    ...
    sub_method_1(obj)
    sub_method_2(obj)
```

Also, there are 2 or more sub methods creates new model objects and link to primary object as foreign key.

```
def sub_method_1(obj):
    obj_new, created = ModelB.objects.get_or_create(...)
    obj.e = new_obj
    obj.save()

def sub_method_2(obj):
    obj_new, created = ModelC.objects.get_or_create(...)
    obj.f = new_obj
    obj.save()
```

But than, when sub methods are done and return back to main method, there are also several save method calls available.

```
def main_method():
    ....
    obj.g = "ert"
    obj.h = 3
    obj.save()
```

Is this approach OK in practice, or there should be only one save at the end of the main method with returning new objects from sub methods and assign objects to foreign key fields before saving the main object?

Will you please lead me a documentation with pros and cons of those approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better choice is use all your methods as a **setter**, and call method *save()* when you really finished to work with instance or you really need that is be present on database.

Of course, depend of your work case, but generally is a better choice :)